# EmojiPopUp inflated above softKeyBoard

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard, emoji

I am trying to use this library https://github.com/vanniktech/Emoji

Actually i wanted to toggle between the soft keyboard and the emoji popup as we do in WhatsApp or any other chat app on the click of smiley button. 
It works fine in almost every device but in some devices like Samsung sm-e700h. The emoji popUp inflates above the soft keyBoard. Any solution??

[image: ScreenShot]

Answer (score 0):

To be honest, I didn`t really get your question, but I try to guess.
The thing you want - auto-close the softKeyboard when emoji window pops up? In this case, you can simply tell the app to close it when some button-which is responsible for emoji pop up window- is pressed. Add below inside that button mentioned above:

```
View view = this.getCurrentFocus();
if (view != null) {  
    InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.getWindowToken(), 0);
}
```

Hope it helps you!

Comment: Nah actually i wanted to toggle between the softkeyboard and the emoji popup as we do in Whatsapp or any other chat app on the click of smiley button. :)
I have updated the question to be more specific.